# Как ставятся запятые в предложениях с "не потому что... а потому что"?

Tags: пунктуация

Примеры (пишу специально почти без запятых, потому что не уверен, где их ставить):

1. Иванов все же устроился на работу не потому что  нуждался в деньгах, а потому что просто надоело сидеть дома.
2. Петров уволился с работы не потому что не вписался в рабочий коллектив, а потому что не нашел общий язык с начальством.

Answer (score 2):

РЕШЕНИЕ

Иванов все же устроился на работу не потому, что нуждался в деньгах, а потому, что просто надоело сидеть дома. Петров уволился с работы не потому, что не вписался в рабочий коллектив, а потому, что не нашел общий язык с начальством.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Постановка знаков препинания в СПП с  ОДНОРОДНЫМИ придаточными и  СОСТАВНЫМИ подчинительными союзами  рассматривается в качестве отдельной темы.

Для однородных придаточных предложений составные подчинительные союзы ВСЕГДА РАСЧЛЕНЯЮТСЯ, при этом местоименные части союзов входят в состав главного предложения.

**Сочинительные союзы соединяют первые (местоименные) части сложных подчинительных союзов как однородные члены в составе главного предложения, а придаточные предложения всегда являются обособленными.**

ПРИМЕРЫ

Он ни с кем не дружил не потому, что не нуждался в людях, а потому, что вся его жизнь ушла куда-то внутрь.

Нехлюдов заехал к тётушкам потому, что их имение было по дороге, и потому, что они очень просили его об этом.

Он очень устал и потому, что дорога была долгой, и потому, что говорить было не о чем.

Comment: Возможны варианты: Нехлюдов заехал к тётушкам, потому что их имение было по дороге и потому что они очень просили его об этом. Ср.: Он не пришёл, потому что заболел (упор в сообщении делается на самый факт неявки, причина ее не подчеркивается). — Он не пришёл потому, что заболел (на первый план выдвигается указание на причину неявки).

Comment: В этой теме речь идет только об ОДНОРОДНЫХ придаточных, соединенных сочинительными союзами.  Теоретически для "Нехлюдова" возможно предложенное оформление, но только из-за наличия одиночного союза И, соединившего придаточные в одну фразу. С точки зрения смысла (структуры, интонации), этот вариант однозначно неудачен, что и соответствует авторскому выбору оформления с расчленением союзов.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенных вами примерах расчленение союза обязательно, т.к. на расчленение влияют сразу два условия: перед союзом стоит отрицание "не", во второй части содержится противопоставление.

Ср.Мелодии, смешиваясь со слезами, текут прямо по вашему нерву к сердцу, и вы плачете ***не оттого, что*** вам печально, ***а оттого, что путь к вам*** вовнутрь угадан так верно и проницательно (Б. Паст.).

> См. [Академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина, § 118.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)